# Onesignal: how to send web push notifications to some users only?

Tags: onesignal

I have a mysql users table: users(id, username, emails, workspaceid)

How can I send onesignal notifications to users who belong to workspaceid=1

```
select * from users where workspaceid=1
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tag everyone who belongs to workspaceid 1.

This will tag the current user of your app.

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("workspaceid", "1");
```

Then when you send a onesignal notification, you can send to everyone that has this tag.

[OneSignal Documentation: Data Tags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-tags)